# Placing two divs side by side while div2 wraps around div1

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have two div elements. Div1 has a set height and div2 has more height than div1.
I want div2 to wrap around div1. Is there a way out in pure CSS3?
[Floats I tried but it doesn't work as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBXB5.png)

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: orange;
  display: inline;
}

.div2 {
  float: left;
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="div1">This is div1. It needs be on the left having particular width

    <p>Not able to sort it out yet</p>

  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <p>Text content of div2. It will wrap around div1 after its height.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're there. The only thing you need to do is remove the float on the second div. This ways the first div is floated and the second div will flow around it.

Just make sure to clear the floats on the next block of the page.

```css
.div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background: orange;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 16px 16px 0;
}

.div2 {
  background: skyblue;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="div1">This is div1. It needs be on the left having particular width

    <p>Not able to sort it out yet</p>

  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <p>Text content of div2. It will wrap around div1 after its height.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pharetra aliquet tellus nec cursus. Donec quis neque non lectus bibendum condimentum vel quis neque. Nulla facilisi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather It's probably an issue with something conflicting with the styles here. I'd have to see more of the code to figure it out. If you can get it to fail in codepen by adding more content or styles in, I can try to figure it out for you.

Comment: Thank you @David. 
This works in the demo code https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/vYQPrME?editors=1100

Trying to work it out with a bit complicated code in my Project as well. 
Thanks again :) Cheers

Comment: Hey, It worked with a bit of tweak and luck. 
In my code for div1, width was not set I believe due to display inline. I changed to display: Inline-grid and it got sorted. 
Thanks for your time. And Cheers!